# Get access to MS Word macros from PHP

Tags: php, vba, ms-word

The problem is following. I have a tool that generates `.docm` files. These files contain some `macros`. The code of macros has settings information, like `URL`s, etc. I want to somehow access from `PHP` this macros in order to make changes programmatically. This is especially necessary when the whole application with this document generator moves to another server.

Comment: I think the only way you'll be able to do this with PHP is using [COM](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php)

Comment: Thanks, Mark! I will check it. Probably, it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.docm` document can be more or less be considered to be a normal `.zip` file.

You can therefore open your document with some PHP unzipping function/library, thereby gaining access to the included file `word/vbaProject.bin`. You then need find or create a PHP library that can modify this `vbaProject.bin` file.

A quick search pointed me to this answer where the documentation for the `vbaProject.bin` file format is linked to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17538985/1560865

Since the file format seems to be quite complex and there will probably be no PHP library available for it, you might want to look for an easier way though....