# My code is gone, excel cant locate my macroes, but i can see the modules in visual basic

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on an wookbook containing alot of data, formulas and a few important macros for the last two weeks.
I have had no problems with the documents until now.

When i opened the document this morning a message came up

> CAN'T SAVE: There was a problem saving and the AutoSave was disabled. Please Save As or close and reopen the file.

When i try to list my Macros in the developer app, the macros come up as empty.

In Visual Basic i can still see my modules are there, but if i try and open them a half empty window will open and this window does not respond to anything. [image: Picture of Visual Basic Windows]

I have tried to open in savemade, i even tried to recover a former version of the document. But whatever i do doesn't seem to work.

I dont have this problem with other files, so i believe it to be a problem with the settings?

Have anyone tried this befour or might have a solution?

Comment: it seems the file got corrupted, have you tried open & repair? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-a-corrupted-workbook-153A45F4-6CAB-44B1-93CA-801DDCD4EA53

Comment: I have tried, but same problem still occur.

Comment: you can try recovering just the macros from vbaProject.bin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536607/read-vba-macros-or-vbaproject-bin-of-an-excel-file-without-opening-it-in-ms-ex copy your Excel file, change extension to zip, extract `vbaProject.bin` (in `xl`), create a new Excel file, add a module there, save and try to replace it with the one you extracted - hopefully it will work

Comment: I have recovered the macro's, but there is one that doesnt seem to work now....
Anyway, thank you for the help!