# Excel : get a source code of custom function in the '.xlsx' file

Tags: excel

I got excel file : '.xlsx' file.

And there are some custom function like =BlahBlah(par1,par2,par3,par4)

I want to extract the source code of this function.

But in VBA (when I push alt + F11 button), there are no source in module.
So I made '.zip' file to see '.vb' file in my '.xlsx' file.
However, there is only '.xlsx' file in '.zip' file.

Because custom function works well, I think there should be a source code which constitute for this custom function. But I don't know where it is.

Comment: Did you check worksheets codes rather than module? Also there may addin installed to the computer.

Comment: @Harun24HR xlsx doesnt hold any code so its nothing related to the file, just an addin

Comment: The code is probably loaded from an add-in or some separate .xlsb file. The probability of the source being an add-in is higher.

Comment: Thanks for all replies. I didn't think about it. I'll study about add-in. Thanks sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

The  '.xlsx' file doesn't store VBA code and it could be an add-ins.
More details seems to be described.
Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename your MyExcel.xlsm to MyExcel.zip
2. Explore MyExcel.zip to find \xl\vbaProject.bin
3. Tailor approach according to these Microsoft guidelines: [Read VBA macros (or vbaProject.bin) of an Excel file without opening it in MS Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536607/read-vba-macros-or-vbaproject-bin-of-an-excel-file-without-opening-it-in-ms-ex)

Let us know how you make out!