# Extract VBA as TXT from XLSM with Python

Tags: python, excel, vba, openpyxl

I want to extract the `VBA` code from an `.xlsm` file and save it as `.txt` files. Unfortunately, I get only `.bin` files when I unzip the `.xlsm` file which I cannot open with an editor.

Comment: That's how Excel stores the code. If you really want to read the file, have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536607/read-vba-macros-or-vbaproject-bin-of-an-excel-file-without-opening-it-in-ms-ex. Sounds like fun. Not. Any reason you don't want to do this with VBA (access the VBE project object modell, tons of examples around)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`olevba`](https://github.com/decalage2/oletools/wiki/olevba#olevba) :

```
#pip install oletools
import oletools.olevba as olevba

vba = olevba.VBA_Parser("file.xlsm")

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    for *_, n, m in vba.extract_all_macros():
        if n.startswith("Module"):
            print(m, file=f)
```

*NB : If you want to target the Excel objects as well, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/e8ea1e7a-6ac8-4dcb-936b-6ada61c00c86/view-source) approach.*

Output (`output.txt`) :

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Module1"
Sub Foo()

    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "StackOverflow"
    Range("B2").Select
    
End Sub
```

Input used (`file.xlsm`) with [*this*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office#looking-at-the-code) code :

[image]