# Manipulate .dotm files without launch MS Word

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

Is it possible to manipulate .dotm files without launch MS Word (even in the background!)?
I'm trying to find a way to export/import the modules (.bas, .cls, .frm and .frx) contained in these files (to version control system).

I can launch MS Word (with `.Visible` property == false), open the .dotm file and do this (loop through `VBComponents`), but is this possible without launching Word?

Sth like DocumentFormat.OpenXml package (Open-XML-SDK) to manipulate document content without opening file.

I have a lot of macros loaded at AutoStart (with code to connecting to some webservices) and Ms Word can launch very long time, so I want to avoid launching Word even in background.

Comment: dotm files are just zip-archives with a bunch of xml files inside, you can just unpack it and do whatever you want.

Comment: Yes, but code modules are in compiled .bin file inside .dotm.

Comment: Duplicate (except it's Word) of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536607/read-vba-macros-or-vbaproject-bin-of-an-excel-file-without-opening-it-in-ms-ex ?